# How do you delete your profile?

Tags: discussion

So how do you do that?

The help center is no help at all. And I really really really want to delete my profile.

Answer (score 3):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account:

> If your account has voted or posted:
>
> Edit the "About Me" section of your profile to say “please delete me”.
>   edit profile
>
> Contact us to request deletion.

Comment: Thank you Brian

Comment: @xxx - I understand you are annoyed, but keep in mind that you're basically mad at ~4 site members who would like to help you improve one of your questions - deleting all your content and permanently abandoning the site is probably an overreaction.  Perhaps sleep on it, talk to us mods for help.  You can remove the note in your profile to prevent deletion sometime in the next 23 hours. We'd love to have you stay on the site and keep participating with us.

Comment: You go and work on something that means something to you for two hours, then watch as 4 people squash and treat it like it was nothing. Hon' the word is not annoyed. However you are right, I was overreacting.

Comment: @xxx sure.  Just consider that from their point of view, they weren't looking to go squash someone's dream today, they thought they were helping workshop a question. I definitely understand that the way it came off was upsetting, and I'm interested in how we can add a more empathetic aspect to the site's otherwise admirable "let's all pitch in together" nature, when the pitching in leaves someone feeling run over.

Comment: I'm going to add a second answer to http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3512/why-people-are-being-so-rude based on insights from this issue.

Comment: @xxx done, would value your thoughts as well over there on how we can make site operations more empathetic.

Comment: Thank you for catching me last night I will take a look at it.