# Why did the Community user delete one meta post by a deleted user, but not another?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, user-accounts, community-bot

The user lately known as **xxx** got their account-deletion request fulfilled earlier today. Shortly after, it appears that [the meta post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/the-difference-between-opinion-driven-questions-and-experience-based-questions) (10k users) at the centre of that event was deleted, while [this related one](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3517/how-do-you-delete-your-profile) by xxx wasn't.

Why is that?

I don't know that we really *need* the first meta post in an undeleted form anyway—but I didn't particularly think it merited deletion either. I'm more curious/alarmed that something disappeared silently by an automatic site mechanism that I wasn't aware existed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[From the FAQ:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

> - The system will automatically delete any question (and its answers) or answer with a score less than 0 when its owner's account is deleted.

One of those posts scores < 0, the other does not.

Comment: Makes perfect sense on main, and reasonable enough on meta.